# UISlider thumb moving without touching thumb

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am using `UISlider` in my project. Normally, thumb should move as soon as we touch and drag the thumb. But, in my case, thumb moved while I touched on the edge of it  without touching it. Like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 200, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-30, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:self.slider];
```

Why the thumb moved and how to deal with it? My target is that, thumb will move only if I thouch and drag it, and will not move when I touched on the edge of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to use taoGesture with `UISlider`, so first add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your slider object then set its value in action method of selector of gestureRecognizer.

Add following code after you have added slider in your View.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSliderTap:)];
[self.slider addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Now in `onSliderTap` you can get the location point then update the value of the slider

```
- (void)onSliderTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    float width = self.slider.frame.size.width;
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    CGFloat sliderX = self.slider.frame.origin.x;
    float newValue = ((point.x - sliderX) * self.slider.maximumValue) / width;
    [self.slider setValue:newValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following code :

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {

     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)];
     [slider addGestureRecognizer:tapGest];

 }

 - (void)sliderTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)tapGest 
 {
        UISlider* slider = (UISlider*)tapGest.view;
        if (slider.highlighted)
            return; // tap on thumb, let slider deal with it
        CGPoint pt = [tapGest locationInView: slider];
        CGFloat percentage = pt.x / slider.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat delta = percentage * (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue);
        CGFloat value = slider.minimumValue + delta;
        [slider setValue:value animated:YES];

  }
```